# dl - multiple definitions for the same term

Tags: html

Is it allowed to use definition list tag like this

```
<dl class="feature-list">

<dt>Stackoverflow</dt>
<dd>Is a nice place place to find some answers</dd>

<dt>Stackoverflow</dt>
<dd>Has a cool team</dd>

<dt>Stackoverflow</dt>
<dd>Welcomes your contribution</dd>

<dt>Stackoverflow</dt>
<dd>is simply amasing</dd>

</dl>
```

The idea is to have a product feature list, while every feature starts with the product name. But product name is the same for every feature. If that is not an allowed usage, what will be the most suitable layout for such a case?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have more than one description for the same term, you'll mark it up as one dt followed by as many dd elements as you need.

Comment: @BoltClock True, but this time screen-design asks for something like what I described in the question.

Comment: Allowed? Sure, it'll validate. Semantically though it's confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to HTML 4.01, the `dl` element has been defined as a definition list, though with notes that make it questionable whether this was really meant. In HTML5 CR, the [`dl` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) is a description list, representing “an association list consisting of zero or more name-value groups”. So there is not much of semantics here, just an abstract structure. So more or less anything that matches the syntax can be said to be conforming, and the syntax has always permitted markup as in the question.

A list where each “value” (`dt` element) has the same content looks odd, but there is nothing formally wrong with it. Associating different “values” with the same “name”, even when the “name” is repeated, can be seen as a legitimate use of an association list.

Besides, there is no evidence of browsers or search engines assigning any particular structural meaning to `dl`, i.e. the real effect of using it is the default rendering you get with it. Thus, if such rendering is OK, and a suitable basis for the more detailed rendering you are aiming at, `dl` is suitable.